# Call AWS Lambda function from React-Native

Tags: amazon-web-services, function, react-native, aws-lambda, call

I have build a simple function in AWS Lambda which sends sms using Twilio service. I now want to call that function from my React-Native app. 
Do you have any suggestion to that?

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways to invoke the AWS Lambda from your React-Native application

**Direct invocation using AWS browser SDK**

You can use [lambda#invoke](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#invoke-property) API to invoke your Lambda function from your React-Native app. Catch here is that you'll have to ship AWS credentials with your app. These credential will have permission to invoke the Lambda function.

**Indirect onvocation using API Gateway**

You can gate your Lambda function behind an API Gateway ([API Gateway + Lambda integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html)). Then you can use standard JavaScript HTTP utilities to make REST calls to you API Gateway resource. This API Gateway resource will be responsible for invoking your Lambda function.

I prefer second method because API Gateway provides [throttling support](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html) and we don't have to ship credentials with the app.